# Understanding training plan notation

Tags: training, triathlon

Not sure if this is the right place to post, but I saw this training plan which I want to start following, and I do not understand how to interpret it. So for example:

Day 1 says 1000m swimming but the main set is 6*50 = 300m. Where do the rest of the meters go? What am I meant to do?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  This site is for competitive sports; triathalon would generally fall under [fitness.se], so I'll migrate the question there.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the full program -- or can you provide a link? I guarantee the program creator has put what they'd like you to fill those meters with in the program itself (warm-ups, cooldowns, technique, etc.)

Comment: @C.Lange https://media.immediate.co.uk/volatile/sites/34/pdf This is where it comes from, and from what I found they don't. Still combing through different things, though.

Answer (score 5):

In general, any kind of "I don't understand this specific training plan" question should be directed towards the authors of that training plan or, if one exists, a community specifically dedicated to that training plan or training plans by the same author.

That said, I would speculate that this training plan includes instructions for warm-ups and cool-downs for interval training, and that for the interval training days, the total time or distance is the sum of the warm-up, main sets and cool-down.

Also, the "@ PE" refers to the intensity at which the training is to be performed, on a 10 point rate of perceived exertion (RPE) scale, where 5-6 is a level where holding a conversation would be possible but a little difficult, 7-8 would be had enough that speaking would be very difficult, 8-9 would be gasping for breath, and 10 would be an absolutely maximum effort.